# Using a triple nested for loop to increase the length and count of the rows printed

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-for-loop

I am curious as to how to code something like this:

```
##
##
####
####
####
####
######
######
######
######
######
######
########
########
########
########
########
########
########
########
```

Here is what I have tried:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i += 2) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.print('#');
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This code displays:

```
##
####
######
########
```

But it doesn't print the lines as many times as how many characters are there.

So basically, it increments by 2, and then it displays the same amount of lines as the amount of characters inside of the loop. I cant figure this out.

What would the third nested for loop look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done with one loop using `String::repeat` / `Collections.nCopies` to create a row containing N `#` characters and then create N rows:

**1. `String::repeat`**
Instance method [`String::repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) available since JDK 11 released in September 2018

```java
for (int i = 2; i <= 8; i += 2) {
    String row = "#".repeat(i) + "\n";
    String rows = row.repeat(i);
    System.out.print(rows);
}
```

**2. `String::join` + `Collections.nCopies`**

- Static method [`String::join`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...)) is available since JDK 8
- Static method [`Collections::nCopies`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,T)) available since [JDK 1.2](http://www.eli.sdsu.edu/courses/fall98/cs596/notes/api2/api2.html)

```java
import static java.lang.String.join;
import static java.util.Collections.nCopies;

//...

for (int i = 2; i <= 8; i += 2) {
    String row = join("", nCopies(i, "#"));
    String rows = join("\n", nCopies(i, row));
    System.out.println(rows);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd use an other loop between both of your loops.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i += 2) {
    for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print('#');
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
##
##
####
####
####
####
######
######
######
######
######
######
########
########
########
########
########
########
########
########
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use two non-nested loops inside the first one. See this example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i += 2) {
        // use a StringBuilder to build up the line to be printed
        StringBuilder lineBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        // then use one loop to build the line with the desired amount of #
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            lineBuilder.append('#');
        }
        // and then use an identical loop, but this time print the line
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.println(lineBuilder.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The result is the desired one (omitted for brevity here).

Answer (score 0):

We add another loop:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i += 2)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                System.out.print('#');
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One-semicolon solution with a single for loop using [`String#replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method *since: 1.5*:

```java
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    // print one line containing
    // newline symbols '\n'
    System.out.print(Collections
            // 'i * 2' copies of rows "##\n"
            // returns List<String>
            .nCopies(i * 2, Collections
                    // 'i * 2' copies of string "#"
                    // returns List<String>
                    .nCopies(i * 2, "#")
                    // List<String> to string
                    // [#, #]
                    .toString()
                    // #, #]
                    .replace("[", "")
                    // #, #
                    .replace("]", "")
                    // ##\n
                    .replace(", ", "") + "\n")
            // List<String> to string
            // [##\n, ##\n]
            .toString()
            // ##\n, ##\n]
            .replace("[", "")
            // ##\n, ##\n
            .replace("]", "")
            // ##\n##\n
            .replace(", ", ""));
```

---

Solution with *a double nested for loop* using [`String#join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) method *since: 1.8*:

```java
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i * 2; j++) {
        String[] arr = new String[i * 2];
        Arrays.fill(arr, "#");
        System.out.print(String.join("", arr));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Solution with *a double nested [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)* using [`String#repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) method *since: Java 11*:

```java
IntStream.range(1, 5)
        .forEach(i -> IntStream.range(0, i * 2)
                .forEach(j -> System.out.println("#".repeat(i * 2))));
```

---

Output:

```
##
##
####
####
####
####
######
######
######
######
######
######
########
########
########
########
########
########
########
########
```